# How can i make chart to show price in range?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lightweight-charts

I am using `lightweight-charts` for drawing financial charts for stock data.

A part of code for drawing chart is:

```js
useEffect(() => {

        if (ref.current) {
            ref.current.innerHTML = "";
            const chart = createChart(ref.current, {
                lineVisible: false, width: 400, height: 300, layout: {
                    background: { color: "#1e2125" },
                    textColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
                },
                leftPriceScale:{
                    borderVisible:false,
                    autoScale:true
                },
                rightPriceScale:{
                    borderVisible:false,
                    autoScale:true
                },
                
                grid: {
                    horzLines: {
                        visible: false,
                    },
                    vertLines: {
                        visible: false,
                    },
                },
                crosshair: {
                    mode: CrosshairMode.Magnet,
                },
                
                timeScale: {
                    minBarSpacing: 0.001,
                    borderVisible: false,
                    fixLeftEdge: true,
                    fixRightEdge: true,
                },
                priceScale:{
                    fixLeftEdge:true,
                    fixRightEdge:true,
                    minBarSpacing:0.001,
                },                
                handleScroll: false,
                handleScale: false,
            });          

           
            const areaSeries = chart.addAreaSeries();
            const data = [
                { time: '2022-02-16', value: 516.7 },
                { time: '2022-02-15', value: 524.8},
                { time: '2022-02-14', value: 501.4 },
                { time: '2022-02-11', value: 529.6 },
                { time: '2022-02-10', value: 540.55 },
                { time: '2022-02-09', value: 535.25 },
                { time: '2022-02-08', value: 531.35 },
                { time: '2022-02-07', value: 533.25 },
                { time: '2022-02-04', value: 530.3},
                { time: '2022-02-03', value: 540.1 },
                { time: '2022-02-02', value: 539.8 },
                { time: '2022-02-01', value: 532.3 },
                { time: '2022-01-31', value: 538.3 }
              ];
            //areaSeries.barsInLogicalRange            
            areaSeries.setData(data);
            setPriceRange(data);

            
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
            chartObj.current && chartObj.current.remove();
        }
    }, [ref.current]);

return (

<div ref={ref} className="alphachart_container">

            </div>
)
```

However, it doesn't look as expected. Price range on right is not as expected.Ideally i want to set priceRange under certain values.

```js
const [visiblePriceRange,setVisiblePriceRange] = useState({ from: 88888888188181818, to: -2222222222});
const setPriceRange = (data)=>{
        let min = Math.min(...data.map(x=>x.value),visiblePriceRange.from);
        let max = Math.max(...data.map(x=>x.value),visiblePriceRange.to);
        let offset = (max - min)/10;
        setVisiblePriceRange({from:min-offset,to:max+offset});
       //Now i want that i should only show these price range on y-axis
    }
```

I have looked into the [documentation](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/PriceRange) about `minValue` and `maxValue` but it didn't help as i cannot figure out the exact syntax.

My current chart looks like this:

[image]

I would like to have price range between around 498 to 544.(rounded off to the nearest integer for the sake of convenience).How may i do this?

Comment: Can you create a repro on jsfiddle/codesandbox for your issue? It seems that it should work out of the box without any issues. Providing `autoscaleInfoProvider` is exceptional case when you want to override the default behaviour which is based on the data in visible range.

Comment: @timocov  I guess this issue was because i included `ref.current` in the `useEffect` dependency which was rendering the chart twice.The issue was no longer there when i put empty array in its dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have looked into the documentation about `minValue` and `maxValue` but it didn't help as i cannot figure out the exact syntax.

Sounds like this is what you're seeking then? Here's an example from [another documentation page](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/SeriesOptionsCommon#autoscaleinfoprovider). Looks like you just need to add `priceRange` like you did with `timeScale`, `priceScale`, etc.

```js
const firstSeries = chart.addLineSeries({
    autoscaleInfoProvider: () => ({
        priceRange: {
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 100,
        },
    }),
});
```